# Battery hull/foil damaged while changing display of a smartphone

Tags: batteries, cellphone

The silver foil of my smarthphone's battery got damaged while I exchanged the touchscreen:
[image: damaged foil]
The battery was glued to the body of the phone and I didn't manage to remove it without damage to the foil.
Now I have two questions:
1) What is the purpose of the foil? Is it there only for protection of the other parts of the battery or is it a vital part of the battery?
2) Can the battery still be used or does it have to be replaced?

Comment: Probably just damaged the outer skin, but I'd seriously consider disposing of it (responsibly) and getting a new one.

Comment: That is the foil that holds in the electrolyte. Your battery is, or soon will be, worthless.

Comment: Damage to the foil was what caused the Samsung Galaxy fires, wasn't it?

Comment: @pjc50 - That information will be officially released on Sunday!

Comment: I personally would just not even run the risk. I've seen them swell, and that could cause damage in another. Not to mention, with all the drama of batteries in cell phones lately, not even worth the risk. Just youtube a lipo exploding, might sway your mind.

Comment: The Galaxy fires were from the battery expanding because they made the enclosure too small. When the battery charged it swelled and all sorts of bad things happened. Funny thing is I think there were less then 100 recorded cases out of the millions of phones sold, but no one wants their house burned down

Comment: The foil forms part of the gas and vapour barrier.  If you reseal the breaks perfectly the battery may still last a while but no way to know how long, if you leave it open and there is no other barrier the battery will surely fail.  I would not place that battery into a phone of mine that is ever left unatended.   Solder a resistor and LED onto it and use it as a torch while it has charge. I would store the battery in a clay pot or metal tin until disposal.

Comment: @KalleMP Finally the answer that I was waiting for! If you post as an answer, I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metallised foil forms part of the gas and vapour barrier of the cell and is there partly to keep moisture and excess oxygen out.

If you reseal the breaks perfectly the battery may still last a while but no way to know how long as the amount of atmospheric moisture that has entered is impossible to determine.

If you leave the breaks open and there is no other barrier inside the battery will surely fail.

I would not place that cell into a phone of mine that is ever left unattended.

I might solder a resistor and an LED onto it and use it as a torch while it has charge but keep it stored outside in a clay pot or metal tin until eventual disposal.

There are many descriptions of damaged Li-Po cells overheating and sometimes catching fire but there are also those tortured cells where only some heat was generated.  The amount of remaining charge also affects the amount of energy inside that can be released from a short circuit.  The amount of lithium is generally small so the danger from a discharged battery is less.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely only "cosmetic damage," but **in case it is not**, is it worth taking the risk, to save the cost of replacing the battery?  If it is a battery that has had a lot of use, you might be close to having to replace it anyway, so if the cost is not too much, you should definitely replace the battery.